# Windows 8 integration into GRUB

Tags: grub2, windows

I would like to integrate Windows 8 integrate into grub without its loader. Can I do this? If yes, how? Loader loads slowly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any alternative boot loader for newer Windows versions. Grub and others only call Microsoft's bootloader when you select the corresponding menu entry.

Comment: This should really be a comment :)